# C++ : Dynamic C-String Usage in ifstreamObject.getline(c string, char limit)

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, dynamic-arrays, c-strings

I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically allocate space to a char aray equal to the amount of spaces in the line from the file while use the getline method. (C++)

example

```
int main(){    
    char *theLine;
    ifstream theFile;

    //set theLine = new char[sizeOftheFileLine]
    //is there a way do the above
    theFile.getline(theLine, 500);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `std::getline`, you get the desired behavior.

```
std::string theLine;
std::ifstream theFile;

// ....

std::getline(theFile, theLine);
```